# how to submit a form using <button type="submit"> tag

Tags: javascript, php

I make a login form and i use `<button type="submit">` but it is not working.when i use the `<input type="submit">` it totally works...Is there any method in java script to use the `<button type="submit">` to submit the form?

```
    <form class="modal-content animate" method="post">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
    </div>

   <div class="container">
    <label><b>Program name</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Program name" name="Pname" required>

    <label><b>Authentication ID</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Authentication ID" name="psw" required>

    <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
   </div>
   <?php
   error_reporting(0);
    session_start();
    include("connection.php");
   $Pname=$_POST['Pname'];
   $psw=$_POST['psw'];
    $_SESSION['$Pname']=$Pname;
   if($_POST['submit'])
   {
      if($Pname=="" or $psw=="")
    {
    //echo '<p align="center" style="color:red">plz enter all info</p>';
    }
       else
    {
       $sql="select * from login where psw='$psw'";
        $rData=mysql_query($sql);
        $res=mysql_fetch_array($rData);
         if($res['Pname']==$Pname && $res['psw']==$psw)
      {
           header("location:po.php?psw=$psw");
       }
        else
       {
        echo '<p align="center" style="color:red">invalid user name and  password';

       }
     }
     }
   ?>
```

here when i use `<input type="submit" name="submit">` it works but when i use    `<button type="submit">` i doesn't work...so how can i use button to work?

Comment: *"i use the but it is not working.But when i use the it totally works"* - I think I just read that three times and I still don't know what is going on.

Comment: Anyway, you know there is a `<input type="submit>` that is specifically designed to send a form?

Comment: the code was not visible at first...now its ok

Comment: it will work if you use `bootstrap`.

Comment: "_I make a login form and i use `<button type="submit">` but it is not working._" what exactly "_is not working_"? do you mean that the form data isn't getting sent to the server-side (i.e. PHP) code, or something else?

Comment: now it is fixed already. I have done it long before.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit a form through JavaScript by calling `.submit()` on the form in click event handler of button.